# Circular, singly linked where the nodes are deleted one after another

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, circular-list

Good evening, my program for the following task is not really doing what it is supposed to do and i can not find the error.

"A group of n persons is arranged in a circle and these persons are numbered by 1 to n. Furthermore, a fixed
natural number m is given. Now, starting to count from person 1, the m-th person is removed from the
circle and the counting starts again from the next person. This is repeated until only one person remains.
The task ist to find the number L(n, m) ∈ {1, ..., n} of this last person.
For fixed n and m this problem can be solved by a program where the circle of persons is represented by a
circular, singly linked list, i.e., a singly linked list where the “last” entry points to the “first” entry

Examples: L(n=7, m=4) = 2, L(21, 3) = 2, L(100, 10) = 26"

When, for example, I first input n=7 & m=4, then give out list and then start the deleting process i get this output:

```
1) input n&m
 2) give out list
 3) start deleting process
 4) END
1
n: 7
m: 4

 1) input n&m
 2) give out list
 3) start deleting process
 4) END
2
1->2->3->4->5->6->7

 1) input n&m
 2) give out list
 3) start deleting process
 4) END
3
The last person is: 7
 1) input n&m
 2) give out list
 3) start deleting process
 4) END
1
n: 6
m: 2
```

it says the last person to remain is 7, which is untrue. I think it always says n is the last person no matter what the input is for m. It also only "works" for one cycle. After i choose option 3) the first time i still can input new numbers n&m, however then the program seems to stop working at all.

Thank you for your time & help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int n,m;

struct s_ring
{
    unsigned int position;
    struct s_ring *next;
};
typedef struct s_ring *t_ring; 
t_ring allocate(void)  
{
    t_ring pointer;
    pointer=(t_ring)malloc(sizeof(*pointer));
    if(pointer==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    pointer->next=NULL;
    return pointer;
}
void circle(t_ring start, t_ring q, int i, int n)
{
    t_ring p=start;
    while(p->next!=NULL && p->next->position<q->position)
        p=p->next; 
    if(i<n)
    {
        q->next=p->next;
        p->next=q;
    }
    if(i==n)
    {
        q->next=start->next;
        p->next=q;
        start=q;
    }
    return;
}
void print_list(t_ring p)
{
    unsigned int i=p->position;
    while(i!=p->next->position)
    {
        printf("%u->",p->position);
        p=p->next;
    }
    printf("%u\n",p->position);
    return;
}
void delete_m(t_ring pointer,t_ring start,int m)
{
    t_ring p=start,q;
    int i=1;
    while(p->position != p->next->position)
    {
        p=p->next;
        i++;
        if(i==m)
        {
            q=p->next;
            p->next=p->next->next;
            free(q);
            i=1;
        }
    }
    if(p->position==p->next->position)
    {
        pointer=p->position;
    }

    return pointer;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    unsigned int op;
    t_ring start, 
           pointer;
    pointer=start;
    start=allocate();
    do
    {
        printf("\n 1) input n&m " );
        printf("\n 2) give out list " );
        printf("\n 3) start deleting process " );
        printf("\n 4) END \n" );
        scanf("%u",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("n: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            printf("m: ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
            for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                pointer=allocate();
                pointer->position=i;
                circle(start,pointer,i,n);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            print_list(start->next);
            break;
        case 3:
            delete_m(pointer,start,m);
            printf("The last person is: %d",*pointer);
        }
    }
    while(op!=4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to debug the program? The best way to do that is to run your program in a debugger. And/or even add more debug print statements. It is best to learn to debug effectively yourself rather than turning to Stack Overflow too early.

Comment: `I input n=7 & m=4 it` - please post the exact whole input from the beginning of your program and exact output the program is giving.

Comment: `typedef struct s_ring *t_ring; ` - Not a good idea to hide pointers.

Comment: I tried using the debugger, but it won't work somehow. Already reinstalled codeblocks serveral times and  made sure Iused the correct files. But somehow the debugger is always missing. I know its better to learn yourself, but i'm sadly running out of time for this homework.

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect at least because the function `delete_m` has the return type `void` but returns `pointer`.:)

```
void delete_m(t_ring pointer,t_ring start,int m)
{
    //...
    return pointer;
}
```

I can suggest the following approach that is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ring_list
{
    unsigned int n;
    struct ring_list *next;
};

void display( struct ring_list *head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        struct ring_list *tail = head;

        do
        {
            printf( "%u -> ", head->n );

        } while ( ( head = head->next ) != tail );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void clear( struct ring_list **head )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        struct ring_list *current = *head;

        *head  = current == ( *head )->next ? NULL : ( *head )->next;

        free( current );
    }

}

void init( struct ring_list **head, unsigned int n )
{
    if ( *head ) clear( head );

    struct ring_list *tail = *head;

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( struct ring_list ) );
        ( *head )->n = i + 1;
        if ( i == 0 ) tail = *head;
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    *head = tail;
}

unsigned int remove_each_n( struct ring_list **head, unsigned int n )
{
    struct ring_list **initial_head = head;

    unsigned int result = 0;

    if ( *head != NULL && n != 0 )
    {
        --n;

        while ( *head != ( *head )->next )
        {
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                head = &( *head )->next;
            }

            struct ring_list *current = *head;
            *head = current->next;
            if ( ( *head )->next == current ) ( *head )->next = *head;
            free( current );
        }

        result = ( *head )->n;
    }

    *initial_head = *head;

    return result;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    struct ring_list *head = NULL;

    unsigned int n = 7;
    unsigned int m = 4;

    init( &head, n );

    display( head );

    unsigned int result = remove_each_n( &head, m );

    printf( "L( %u, %u ) = %u\n\n", n, m, result );

    n = 21;
    m = 3;

    init( &head, n);

    display( head );

    result = remove_each_n( &head, m );

    printf( "L( %u, %u ) = %u\n\n", n, m, result );

    n = 100;
    m = 10;

    init( &head, n);

    result = remove_each_n( &head, m );

    printf( "L( %u, %u ) = %u\n\n", n, m, result );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> null
L( 7, 4 ) = 2

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12 -> 13 -> 14 -> 15 -> 16 -> 17 -> 18 -> 19 -> 20 -> 21 -> null
L( 21, 3 ) = 2

L( 100, 10 ) = 26
```